# Mobile Application Payment Support - Pay via BHIM

Tags: android, ios, payment-gateway, ccavenue, upi

I am having a new discussion for developing Android and iPhone mobile applications for selling customer's products online. The requirement is such that user can purchase products by making payment using credit,debit, netbank, BHIM and UPI mode from the application.

I have searched for payment gateways and noticed CC Avenue supports payments other than BHIM. https://www.ccavenue.com/upi.jsp

I have found its possible invoke UPI deeplink URL for opening application but not sure about the payment response success or not.

I would like to know is it possible to integrate such an option "Pay with BHIM" in the mobile application, so that user can make payment using the BHIM application?

or

Is there any SDK for integrating the BHIM payment in a 3rd party app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer this link and you can access BHIM from your app.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50860569/1675595

Answer (score 1):

To integrate UPI SDK in you android app you have to partner with a bank which is offering this service.. see below link 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41010744/9287163

But if you want to create a demo project or see on there is an open-source Android SDK that implements NPCI's payment procedure for UPI below is the link

https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/upi-dropin

the below on e is also helpfull
https://github.com/ashishmodak/upi-android-integration

Comment: Thank You Krishank Tripathi.       But CC Avenue has UPI payment support. BHIM is a UPI based transaction application. I would like to place button in mobile app's payment page says "Pay using BHIM". On click it will open BHIM application installed in user mobile with some parameters such as UPI id of the shop, amount, purpose,..., after making payment return to my application with status success or failure. Is this possible?